# Update dynamic column of a table with row value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Customer table**

[image: Customer]

**Mapping table**

[image: ColumnMapping]

I got 2 tables with dynamic columns. 
Mapping table contains the column name, default value of the column and other things. I am trying to update default value in customer table if the value is null.

my expected result is

[image: Result table]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is a dynamic column?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use multiple update statements if there are only 6 fields (or are there a lot of columns).

Comment: These columns are generated depending on uploaded file. So currently there is no limit for the columns. I trying to implement an update statement without specifying or  minimally specifying column names

Comment: You will have to create a table in the database and not a temp table. Loop through the columns of that table and update the columns dynamically. You can drop the table in the stored procedure later. If you need some code let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to account for each column in the query.  Here is one method:

```
update c
    set name = coalesce(c.name, def.name),
        country = coalesce(c.country, def.country),
        . . .
    from customer c cross join
         (select max(case when columnname = 'name' then defaultvalue end) as name,
                 max(case when columnname = 'country' then defaultvalue end) as country,
                 . . .
          from mapping
         ) def
    where c.name is null or c.country is null or . . .;
```

All that said, you probably want to look into `default` constraints on the table.  You would be storing this within the table definition, but if the defaults do not change, then that is simpler than using a separate `mapping` table.

Comment: Actually these 2 are temp tables which needs formatting before insert into main table. So i am not able to use default in table def.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i am not able define the column name because it will vary each time depending on file upload.

I solved this issue by using following method.

```
DECLARE @min INT
DECLARE @max INT

SELECT @min = MIN(ID) FROM #tempMap
SELECT @max = MAX(ID) FROM #tempMap

WHILE (@min <= @max)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @column NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @columnvalue NVARCHAR(MAX),  
            @QueryDefValUpdate NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT
        @column = ColumnName,
        @columnvalue = Defaultvalue 
    FROM
        #tempMap 
    WHERE
        ID = @min   

    SELECT @QueryDefValUpdate = 'UPDATE [#TempCustomer] SET ' + @column + 
                                '=' + @columnvalue + ' WHERE (' + @column + 
                                ' IS NULL OR LEN(' + @column + ') < 1)  '

    EXEC sp_executesql @QueryDefValUpdate       

    SELECT @min = @min + 1
END
```

Thanks for the help.